# How to see method parameters with Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Probably I didn't install something, but can't see Android SDK method descriptions (also with Ctrl+Q) in Kotlin. Also instead of normal parameters like `text`, `position`, `start` I see `p0`, `p1`, etc.

Is it normal?

[image]

Comment: You need to grab the sources for whatever compile SDK version you're using from the SDK manager. If you jump into the source of one of these classes, you should get a download prompt for it automatically as well.

Comment: @zsmb13, thanks, I will try to download. Pls, add your answer here so that I could add rate to you.